# No of BST possible with n unlabelled nodes

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, catalan

I was recently asked to tell the no of BST possible with n unlabelled nodes in an interview. But I couldn't understand the point of unlabelled nodes in BST and was not able to answer properly. What should be the appropriate answer to this question?

Comment: That the "S" in "BST" is irrelevant when nodes have no information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I would also have expressed my surprise when presented with BSTs with unlabelled nodes. BSTs only make sense when nodes carry information.

I suppose they just meant binary trees. And for that counting problem you seem to have already answered the question by adding the `catalan` tag.

If we call *C<sub>n</sub>* the number of binary trees that can be made with *n* nodes, then we can break the problem down to the possibilities for the *subtrees* of the root. First count the number of trees when all the non-root nodes are in the left subtree, then when one of them is actually in the right subtree, ...etc, and total all those counts.

- *C<sub>0</sub>* = 1
- *C<sub>n+1</sub> = ∑<sub><sub>i=0..n</sub></sub>C<sub>i</sub> C<sub>n-i</sub>*

... and this is exactly the recurrence relation given for [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Properties).

And it is not hard to write this as a recursive function (pseudo code):

```
CountBT(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1 
    total = 0
    for i = 0 to n:
        total = total + CountBT(i) * CountBT(n - i)
    return total
```

Using memoization this could be made more efficient.